# некорректно работает slideUp

Tags: jquery

Делаю раскрытие подменю по нажатию, столкнулся с проблемой что slideUp отложенную функцию выполняет 2 раза(до slideUp и по его завершению). если заменить на slideToggle, то он функцию 2 раза выполняет после того как сам выполнится.

В чем тут проблема?

```
$("#horizontal-multilevel-menu").on("click", "li a", function(){
    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")){
        $("#horizontal-multilevel-menu li").removeClass( "active");
        $("#horizontal-multilevel-menu li ul").slideUp();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active").find("ul").slideToggle();
    }else{
        $("#horizontal-multilevel-menu li ul").slideUp("normal", function(){
            alert();
            $("#horizontal-multilevel-menu li").removeClass( "active");
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, мало что понятно. Попробуйте сформулировать ваш вопрос иначе и добавить в вопрос воспроизводимый код через сниппет.

Comment: возможно что какая-то анимация есть ещё по классу `active`